# Can't return data with CAML Query

Tags: caml-query

i'm new to SharePoint so I might be asking something silly, or maybe doing silly mistakes, but i've looked it up all over and couldn't find a solution.

So Basically I want to access a Sharepoint list and return the values from a single column:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src="http://myWebSite.com/risk/dtm/JS/jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js"></script>
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript' src="http://myWebSite.com/risk/dtm/JS/sputility.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test sharepoint</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='result'></div>
    


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var query = '<Query>'+
                        '<Where>'+
                            '<And>'+
                                '<Eq>'+
                                    '<FieldRef Name="Ambiente"/><Value Type="Text">SAS</Value>'+
                                '</Eq>'+
        /*
                                '<Neq>'+
                                    '<FieldRef Name="IsOldRequest"/><Value Type="Text">Y</Value>'+
                                '</Neq>'+
        */
                            '</And>'+
                        '</Where>'+
                    '</Query>';

        var view = '<ViewFields>'+
                    '<FieldRef Name="Title" />'+
                  '</ViewFields>';
        var htmlTable='';
        var TrainingTitle;
        var RequestStatus;
        var Created;
        var RequestorName;
        var Deployement;
        $().SPServices({
                    operation: "GetListItems",
                    async: false,
                    webURL: 'http://myWebSiteSharepoint.com.br/risk/dtm/gd/Lists/grupos/AllItems.aspx?ShowInGrid=True&View=%7BEC1106D7%2DDCD4%2D4425%2DBC49%2DFEDCCD55AF8A%7D&InitialTabId=Ribbon%2EList&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence',
                    listName: "Grupos e RDOs",
                    CAMLViewFields: view ,
                    CAMLQuery : query ,
                    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                        console.log(xData);
                        console.log(Status);
                        var totalRows = parseInt($(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("rs:data").attr("ItemCount"));
    
                        if(totalRows > 0)
                        {                       
                            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode('z:row').each(function()
                            {
                                TrainingTitle = $(this).attr("ows_TrainingTitle");
                                if(TrainingTitle === undefined)
                                    TrainingTitle = '';

                                RequestStatus = $(this).attr("ows_RequestStatus");
                                if(RequestStatus === undefined)
                                    RequestStatus ='';

                                Created = $(this).attr("ows_Created");
                                if(Created === undefined)
                                    Created ='';

                                RequestorName = $(this).attr("ows_RequestorName");
                                if(RequestorName === undefined)
                                    RequestorName= '';

                                Deployement = $(this).attr("DeployementDate");
                                if(Deployement === undefined)
                                    Deployement ='';
                // Store data in variable once all data in stored append it to table                    
                                htmlTable+="<tr><td>"+RequestStatus +"</td><td>"+TrainingTitle +"</td><td>"+Created+"</td><td>"
                                            +RequestorName +"</td><td>"+ Deployement +"</td></tr>";                                 
                            });
                            //$("#exportToExcel").append(htmlTable);

                        }else{
                            console.log("rows less than 0");
                            console.log(totalRows);
                        }
                    }
        }); 
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, with my console.logs I got the following results:

xData: full javascript object, with 200 status and the following ***responseText:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" lang="pt-br" dir="ltr">
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /><meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" /><meta name="progid" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" /><title>
    Grupos e RDOs - Todos os Itens
</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/risk/dtm/gestaodedados/_themes/1/search-EB0BE372.css?ctag=2"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/risk/dtm/gestaodedados/_themes/1/corev4-AB0302A5.css?ctag=2"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var _fV4UI = true;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1046/init.js?rev=M1qgSOO%2Bkv9U8HtiTmhOpg%3D%3D"></' + 'script>');
document.write('<script type=",
```

It cuts the end, but it seems it is actually connecting to the list, I also got a 200 http code in the list.

> Now for the function Status I got: ParseError.
>
> And for the totalRows I got: NaN.

**I feel like the parseError is where the problem is, but I can't figure out what I did wrong.**

ps: I changed some of the urls for security reasons, but they're working just fine.

Comment: webURL is the URL of the SharePoint web (minus the`/lists` part). Try it with value as 
`http://myWebSiteSharepoint.com.br/risk/dtm/gd`. Just a note: try avoiding `async:false` wherever possible since it blocks the UI thread and leads to poor performance.

Comment: @Akhoy Thank you for the answer, indeed the change made it better since now I get a responseXML in the javascript object. But i'm getting the http://myWebSiteSharepoint.com.br/risk/dtm/gd/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx HTTP POST 500 text/xml in my list, it says internal server error. Maybe it means I cant access it from a web page?

Comment: Now i'm getting the "one or more fields are not installed correctly" despite i'm using internal field names from the url

Comment: Something is wrong with your CAML query then. Try executing it in a CAML query builder and see if it returns results. https://www.u2u.be/software

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only 1 condition no need for `<And>` in CAML query. Update caml query like below,

```
 var query = '<Query>'+
                '<Where>'+
                        '<Eq>'+
                            '<FieldRef Name="Ambiente"/><Value Type="Text">SAS</Value>'+
                        '</Eq>'+
                '</Where>'+
            '</Query>';
```

Update your `CAMLViewFields` ,

```
var view = '<ViewFields>'+
                    '<FieldRef Name="Title" />'+
                    '<FieldRef Name="TrainingTitle" />'+
                    '<FieldRef Name="RequestStatus" />'+
                    '<FieldRef Name="Created" />'+
                    '<FieldRef Name="RequestorName" />'+
                    '<FieldRef Name="DeployementDate" />'+
                  '</ViewFields>';
```

And also update the `DeployementDate` retrieval like below,

```
Deployement = $(this).attr("ows_DeployementDate");
```